# Application freezing?

Tags: c++, windows

Is it possible to write a c++ program that will do the following for a given windows process:

```
1) pause an application
2) copy the memory of that application to the HDD
3) kill the application
4) at a later point start the application in the exact same state it was before by loading the saved memory
```

One would want to do this for many reasons, and I believe it will be especial helpful in debugging.

Comment: Platform? Windows/linux/...? Upvoting because of interest.

Comment: Run the application in a VM, pause or snapshot the VM.

Comment: Windows as I tagged it. VM is a great idea but is it possible without VM?

Comment: Do you want to do all that from another application, or from the application itself?

Comment: From another application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, is not possible. Some of the values in the process image are kernel handles. These will not have a corresponding kernel structure when you restore the image. If you don't believe me, you should believe Raymond Chen: [Why can't the system hibernate just one process?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/20/116749.aspx)

What it is possible is to create a dump, see [How to create a user-mode process dump file in Windows Vista and in Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931673), [`.dump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`MiniDumpWriteDump`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Developers had been successfully used dumps for debugging for many years now...

Comment: I believe you. Aside from this, what will happen with the pointers? I believe it will be impossible to have the exact same pointers, right?

Comment: The pointer will be the same, is all virtual memory. Re-establishing context (eg. a mapped file) is basically impossible w/o some non-existing special kernel support. Use dumps, as I said.

Comment: Aha, I see... Is there any chance for this to work on another OS, like linux?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But [docker](https://www.docker.io/) will get you very close to that, a portable running environment. Is intended for deployment, not for debugging. For debugging Linux ecosystem uses... dumps!